# Вывод фамилий в порядке убывания среднего балла

Tags: c++

Выведите фамилии и имена учащихся в порядке убывания их среднего балла.
Входные данные

Заданы сначала количество учащихся n, затем n строк, каждая из которых содержит фамилию, имя и три числа (оценки по трем предметам: математике, физике, информатике). Данные в строке разделены одним пробелом. Оценки принимают значение от 1 до 5.

Выходные данные

Необходимо вывести пары фамилия-имя по одной на строке, разделяя фамилию и имя одним пробелом. Выводить оценки не нужно. Если несколько учащихся имеют одинаковые средние баллы, то их нужно выводить в порядке, заданном во входных данных.

Sample Input:

```
3
Markov Valeriy 5 5 5
Sergey Petrov 1 1 1
Petrov Petr 3 3 3
```

Sample Output:

```
Markov Valeriy
Petrov Petr
Sergey Petrov
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как это скорее всего школьная задачка, я не стал заморачиваться с сортировкой и реализовал обычную пузырьковую сортировку.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    string surname;
    string name;
    double avg;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    student studs[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int m1, m2, m3;
        cin >> studs[i].surname >> studs[i].name;
        cin >> m1 >> m2 >> m3;
        studs[i].avg = (m1 + m2 + m3) / 3.0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (studs[i-1].avg < studs[i].avg) {
                student ex;
                ex = studs[i - 1];
                studs[i - 1] = studs[i];
                studs[i] = ex;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << studs[i].surname << " " << studs[i].name << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Рабочий пример здесь - https://ideone.com/9F0XDf

Comment: Извините, но данное решение неверное

Comment: Для проверки используется тестовая система и программа не проходит тест

Comment: @Alone_Fox на каком тесте проваливается и с какой ошибкой?

Comment: Не указано, что проверяется в тесте

Comment: @Alone_Fox, можно тогда ссылку на задание и тестирующую систему?